# CMD/BAT. Разбить строку на части и выбрать нужную часть в переменную

Tags: cmd, bat, for, qregexp, substring

Есть файл `test.xml` со строкой вида

```
appId="79B78D1B" appVersion="123" minPlatformVersion="789" minPlatform35Version="465"
```

Нужно взять из этой строки `appVersion="123"` и присвоить переменной значение `123`

разбил строку пробелами

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('findstr appVersion "test.xml"') do echo %%a
```

как найти в ней часть appVersion, причём неизвестно на какой позиции appVersion будет в строке?

Comment: For /F с соотв. параметрами.

Comment: *как найти в ней часть appVersion* Ну... разбить по символу `=` и взять первую подстроку, вероятно. Сравнить с заданным значением и, если совпало, вывести вторую подстроку.

Answer (score 1):

```
For /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%a in (`powershell -command "$xml = [xml] (Get-Content test.xml);$appVersion = $xml.AppDescription.appVersion;$appVersion"`) do set v=%%a
```

Так работает.